# Avoid Service callback when Activity gets closed and re-opened

Tags: android, android-service, listener, android-binder

I have a LocalService that exposes a Binder with some APIs. I create a Service Listener, just like this:

```
if (dataServiceListener == null) {
    dataServiceListener = new DataServiceListener();
    mainActivity.getApplicationContext().bindService
        (new Intent(mainActivity, LocalService.class),
        dataServiceListener.svcConn, mainActivity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

After I call the method that the `Binder` in `dataServiceListener` exposes, I get the response in the `dataServiceListener` `onResult()` method. Up to this point, no kind of issues, everything is working.
Some sort of problem occurs when I close the Activity that is waiting for the Service Listener callback and immediately reopen it. Even though I re-instantiate the `dataServiceListener` in `onCreate()`, I get two callbacks instead of one, the old one from the destroyed Activity and the latter (right) one; this way the results mix up on the UI.
Is there a way to tell the Service or the Service Listener that when the activity finishes, the callbacks must be avoided. Or maybe even destroy the ServiceListener objects.

I think this is the issue that Mark L. Murphy (Commonsware) described in "The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development":

> The biggest catch is to make sure that the activity retracts the listeners when it is done.

How can I do this? Is there a way to get rid of the useless listeners when the activity finishes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue (and no, I haven't been working on it for so long :D).

The callback to the listener was made before the `Fragment`'s `onDestroy` was called. So the boolean "dontupdate" value was never set to false. Overriding `onBackPressed` in the main activity solved the problem, as I invoked a `destroy()` method for each fragment that takes care of setting the boolean value to false.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I was working in a remote sevice using AIDL. I got this problem when i am trying do unregister my listeners using the remove method from ArrayList Collection inside a foreach loop, because I was not using asBinder in the comparision. Searching fora solution, I find out the [RemoteCallbackList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RemoteCallbackList.html) class in Android API. This class does exactly what i needed, and what i think you should do, on a easy way, taken all reponsabilites for the hard work  that involves this task.

From the Android API:

> To use this class, simply create a single instance along with your service, and call its register(E) and unregister(E) methods as client register and unregister with your service. To call back on to the registered clients, use beginBroadcast(), getBroadcastItem(int), and finishBroadcast().

Broadcast sample:

```
int i = callbacks.beginBroadcast();
while (i > 0) {
    i--;
    try {
        callbacks.getBroadcastItem(i).somethingHappened();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    // The RemoteCallbackList will take care of removing
    // the dead object for us.
   }
}
callbacks.finishBroadcast();
```

Answer (score 4):

The code you show is for binding to a service. You do not show where you are registering a listener with that service. You apparently are, based upon your question and your reference to an `onResult()` method. Given the nature of your problem, I am going to guess that what you're doing is:

1. Binding to the service in `onCreate()`
2. In `onServiceConnected()`, you are calling some sort of `setListener()` method on the `Binder`

In that case, if we ignore configuration changes, the proper way to unwind matters would be to, in `onDestroy()`, call some `removeListener()` method on the `Binder`, then call `unbindService()`.

Configuration changes, particularly in a pre-fragment world, make this complicated. It's the reason why [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherAPI) (and the accompanying material in [the book](http://commonsware.com/Android)) is so icky. Binding is twitchy -- if you unbind from the old activity, and nothing else is keeping the service around, the service will shut down before the new activity gets a chance to bind. Binding is also state -- you cannot simply fail to unbind, lest you leak stuff.

So, the recipe becomes:

1. Bind to the service in `onCreate()` using the `Application` `Context`
2. In `onServiceConnected()`, call sort of `setListener()` method on the `Binder`
3. In `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, make note of the fact that you're undergoing a configuration change, and return some `Object` that has your `Binder`, your `Listener`, and all the rest of your state
4. In `onCreate()`, use `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` -- if it is `null`, proceed as normal, but if it is not `null`, hold onto that `Binder` and `Listener` and don't re-bind and re-register the listener
5. In `onDestroy()`, if the flag from Step #3 above is `false` (i.e., we are *not* undergoing a configuration change), call some `removeListener()` method on the `Binder`, then call `unbindService()`.

Using fragments with `setRetainInstance(true)` can probably simplify this some, though I have not worked through a sample for that yet.

Comment: I did just that.
Basically, I have an activity with multiple fragments. Each fragment can have one or more services bindings, because it may need to to multiple tasks at the same time.

In the main activity's `onBackPressed()`, I set all of the service listeners to some not-working state by a `boolean` value. Then I finish the Activity. But this doesn't work as expected: it sure works if I set a breakpoint to the `onBackPressed()` method, but for some sort of reason, without the breakpoint, the `onResult()` method is called before `onBackPressed()`!

Comment: @MacGyver: "I did just that." -- well, your description doesn't seem to match. You will notice, for example, that I do not mention `onBackPressed()`, in part because that's insufficient. "Each fragment can have one or more services bindings, because it may need to to multiple tasks at the same time." -- you should not need multiple bindings for that. You only need one service, and hence one `Binder`.

Comment: Ok, in the fragments' onDestroy() I now have:
`dataServiceListener.serviceBinder.removeListener();`

`getActivity().getApplicationContext().unbindService(dataServiceListener.svcConn);`

However, this doesn't change anything. `removeListener()` just performed a `listener = null` in the `ServiceBinder`.

Comment: I don't know how to help you further. If your problem still is "I get two callbacks instead of one", you need to figure out who is still holding the listener despite your setting it to `null`, and fix that, or something.

Comment: Ok, so are you saying that setting the listener to `null` should get the job done? I think I'm going to write some simple service that basically does nothing and try and play with that.
but why did you mention WeakReferences in your book?

Comment: I'm saying that *something* has to be calling `onResult()` on the listener. Maybe something else is holding the listener and calling `onResult()`. Maybe it's a timing issue based on how you're testing this (e.g., you're testing via orientation changes, and the new activity is created/does the binding/triggers `onResult()` before the old one is destroyed). Maybe it's something else. I can't say, because I'm not in your head, and I can't read your monitor because of the curvature of the Earth (plus, you have it pointing the wrong way). :-)

Comment: LOL, fine then. I'll just put this issue aside and get back on it later, trying to re-implement my app's Service as you suggested me.
One more thing: as I need to make multiple calls to the same binder at the same time, how does the binder can differentiate from the received listeners registered to it? That's why I had multiple bindings in my app.

Comment: "One more thing: as I need to make multiple calls to the same binder at the same time, how does the binder can differentiate from the received listeners registered to it?" -- ideally, you pass the listener in with the operation, rather than the add/remove pattern  you are using. Then, there's no question which listener goes to which operation. In terms of WeakReferences (which probably should be SoftReferences), that's a strategy for dealing with cases when your activity forgets to remove the listener, but it is dependent on the GC system. For your own code, it is better to just do it right.

Comment: Technically, I wasn't using the add/remove pattern, but I was passing my listener to the method in the binder, together with its related parameters. So I really don't understand what is holding my listener. I'll look into it.

Comment: "So I really don't understand what is holding my listener" -- yeah, that definitely sounds odd. It also means that a bunch of my advice related to listeners in this answer isn't relevant...

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. You need to release all the resources,listeners,threads from the service when it finishes.

Comment: And how can I achieve that? I only need to destroy my listeners as soon as the Activity closes (`onBackPressed()`)

Comment: yes you can do it there where your activity finishes and to make sure It is done, you can also override "onDestroy()" method in service..

Comment: I did exactly that, but it looks like the `onDestroy` method gets called right after the onResult, so nothing changes!

Answer (score 1):

Your activity has to register/unregister itself as the listener. You need to use the proper lifecycle callback methods, not `onBackPressed()`. Register `onStart()`, unregister `onStop()`. One way to do it is to make the listener a static member of your service, and provide static register/unregister methods. Then call those from your activity as appropriate.